# UITextField secure text entry whitespace after every character

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have implemented following code to get some whitespaces after every characters.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textField.text];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                             value:@(25)
                             range:NSMakeRange(0,[textField.text length] )];

    self.texpTextField.attributedText = attributedString;
```

but this solution works for non-secure text entry. It is not working for secure text entry.

I want to implement passcode in my textfield. So, secure text is required.

Comment: Why do you need to use kerning for passcode? Maybe you want to use simple whitespace character " "?

Comment: Can you explain the effect you're going for?  UITextField already has a native way to obscure its contents.